# Create an empty table on an Excel sheet via R

Tags: r

i would like to create an empty table via R on an excel file and specify its exact location.

[image: Table structure].

Would appreciate if there was an easy way to do this and add formatting.

Thank you

Expecting an output with the above table image via R.

Answer (score 1):

```
# Create an empty dataframe
num_rows <- 10  # number of rows
num_columns <- 3   # number of columns
empty_df <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = num_columns, nrow = num_rows))
colnames(empty_df) <- c("Column1", "Column2", "Column3")  # specify column names

# install.packages("XLConnect")   # you need this package
library(XLConnect)
wb <- loadWorkbook("File_result.xlsx", create = TRUE)  # name of the excel file
createSheet(wb, name = "Sheet1")  # create a sheet with the name of your choice

# set your start row and start column 
writeWorksheet(wb, empty_df,"Sheet1",startRow = 10, startCol = 3, header = TRUE)

# automatically adjust column width
setColumnWidth(wb, sheet = "Sheet1", column = 3:4, width = -1)
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

This will add a sheet with column names in the excel sheet.

[image]